# How to change Crystal Report DatePicker date format?

Tags: asp.net, datepicker, crystal-reports

I am using date range as a parameter. When I try to run locally it shows the correct format as I expect `dd-MM-yyyy`.

But When I run the project on iis in another server, after I select the date from date picker, it changed into `MM-dd-yyyy`

[image: Crystal DatePicker]

Even in the system date format are same as I expect

[image: System Date Format]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Dateformat of the field in the report.

Comment: I didn't use that field for printing in the report. Then how can I do the format?